# Help with an OpAmp

Tags: operational-amplifier, resistors, voltage-divider

[image]

I need to show that V= 5*V1 - V2

Can anyone give me a hint so that i can proceed with the resolution? Thanks!

Comment: First, label the internal nodes with their voltages; this is surprisingly easy. Then follow the currents. (It may help to set V2=0 in your mind while working out the gain to V1)

Comment: @BrianDrummond I have tried to analize dividing in two circuits and using the  op amp summer...but i get nowhere because i get stuck in the gain of the first opamp.

Comment: Think about this - If the second op amp is working OK, its inputs will be at equal voltages. That means that the left hand op amp is effectively connected to the central node, and you can calculate its gain based on that.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast i can not find the tension, Va at the node between V2 and the two opamps. I got i3=(Vo-Va)/R, i2=(V2-V1)/R and i1=(Va-V1)/R. As i3=i2+i1, i got Vo-Va=V2-V1

Comment: No. Stop. If you can consider the two inputs to the second op amp to be the same, as far as the first op amp is concerned you can get rid of the second op amp (but leave the two inputs tied together), and you can get rid of the second op amp's feedback resistor and the resistor to V2. Now, what is the output and the gain of the op amp?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast sorry...but can you please write it down. I am not reaching it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the first part of the answer. If the second op amp is working correctly, and is an ideal op amp, then its' inputs are at the same voltage. This means that you can calculate the output of the first op amp as

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjLFXH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Once you know how to calculate VA, you can fill in the rest of the circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0vRSd.png)</sup>

Now you can calculate voltages and currents in the feedback resistor.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have spent one day trying to solve this exercise.

Comment: Sorry this might be a noob question. I followed till the part that opamp1 will match the input so the ip1 is also V1 . But how do we calculate Va from there ? Is it from the equation of the normal feedback op-amp , since oa2 will also have ip1 as Va. So will be equivalent to that?

Comment: @DallasCarter - Yeah, it's a noob question, but we all start out that way. Since op amp inputs draw (ideally) no current, the output from VA will flow through the two resistors to ground. Since the same current flows through both resistors, and both resistors have the same resistance, what is the voltage across each resistor? Adding them up gives VA, and you can calculate the gain by comparing this to V1.

Answer (score 0):

Set V1=0;

Vo = 2V1+ (1+1/2) × 2V1= 5V1

Set V2= 0;

Vo= -V1.

Now, with both V1 & V2:

Vo= 5V1-V2